# Finding possible values in vector.

Tags: vectors

Just having some difficulty finding the values of '$P$' in this vector.

Relative to an origin $O$, the position vectors of the points $A$ and $B$ are given as follows:

$\left\lvert OA \right\rvert$ = $2i + 3j - k$  
 $\left\lvert OB \right\rvert$ = $4i - 3j + 2k$

The point $C$ is such that $\left\lvert OC \right\rvert$ = $6j + pk$ where $p$ is a constant.  Given the lengths of $\left\lvert AB \right\rvert$ and $\left\lvert AC \right\rvert$ are equal, find the possible values of $P$.

--

So what I have done so far is as follows:

$ 2i - 6j + 3k = 9j + pk - 2i - k $ 
$4i -15j + 3k = pk - k$

Now what I'm doing may be completely stupid or wrong, so apologies in advance, however any pointers or tips would be much appreciated :)

Thanks again!

Comment: AB =OB-OA and AC=OC-OA after finding these... equate them and find the value of p.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $OA=(2, 3, -1)$, $OB=(4, -3, 2)$ and $OC=(0, 6, p)$ for $p\in\Bbb K $. Now we use the fact that $AB=OB-OA $ and $AC=OC-OA$ to find the vectors  $AB$ and $AC$. We have:
$$AB=(4, -3, 2)-(2, 3, -1)=(2, -6, 3)$$
and:
$$AC=(0, 6, p)-(2, 3, -1)=(-2, 3, p+1)$$
Now we use the formula for the length of a vector in $\Bbb K^3$ which yields:
$$||AB||=\sqrt {(2)^2+(-6)^2+(3)^2}=7$$
and:
$$||AC||=\sqrt {(-2)^2+(3)^2+(p+1)^2}=\sqrt {p^2+2p+14}$$
Now you just set $||AB||=||AC||$, since they have the same length, and solve for $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

It seems that you are confusing the length of a vector with the vector itself. The vector $\overrightarrow{AB}=2\mathbf{i}-6\mathbf{j}+3\mathbf{k}$ has lenght $|\overrightarrow{AB}|=\overline{AB}=\sqrt{(2)^2+(-6)^2+(3)^2}$. Do the same for $|\overrightarrow{AC}|$ and you find the equation that gives the values of $p$.